# Period lattice of entire function

Tags: complex-analysis, periodic-functions

> Let $f$ be an entire function, and let $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{C}$ such that
> $$f(z+\alpha) = f(z) \quad f(z+\beta) = f(z) \quad \forall z \in \mathbb{C}$$
> Then if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$, $\{n\alpha +m\beta: n,m\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that $f$ is constant.

I know I have to come up with some kind of sequence converging to any point on $\mathbb{R}$ but I dont know how to do it, and what it has to do with the fact that $\alpha $ and $\beta$ are linearly independent. The second part is easier, I can just use Liouville's theorem, as f is bounded over the real line because $f(0) = f(n \alpha)$ and f is bounded at 0, but I don't know if I can prove that f is bounded just by looking at if on the real line.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: yes, sorry, m and n are whole numbers.

Comment: Note that $f$ can be entire and bounded on the real line without being constant (think $\sin(z)$), but if $f$ is entire and *constant* on the real line, then $f$ is constant on the complex plane by its power series expansion.

Answer (score 1):

**Case 1** $\alpha, \beta$ are linearly dependent over $\mathbb R$. This means $\beta=s\alpha$ for some $s \in \mathbb R$.

**Show first that**

$$ \mbox{ inf } \{\frac{n\alpha +m\beta}{\alpha}:\frac{n\alpha +m\beta}{\alpha}>0; n,m\in \mathbb{Z}\}=0$$

Indeed, assume by contradiction that
$$
a= \mbox{ inf } \mbox{ inf } \{\frac{n\alpha +m\beta}{\alpha}:\frac{n\alpha +m\beta}{\alpha}>0; n,m\in \mathbb{Z}\}>0
$$

First show that $a \in\mbox{ inf } \{\frac{n\alpha +m\beta}{\alpha}:\frac{n\alpha +m\beta}{\alpha}>0; n,m\in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

Note that otherwise you could find two elements $b,c \in \mbox{ inf } \{\frac{n\alpha +m\beta}{\alpha}:\frac{n\alpha +m\beta}{\alpha}>0; n,m\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ with
$$
a<b<c <\frac{3a}{2} \,.
$$
But then $c-b \in\mbox{ inf } \{\frac{n\alpha +m\beta}{\alpha}:\frac{n\alpha +m\beta}{\alpha}>0; n,m\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ and $c-b <a$ contradicting the definition of $\mbox{inf}$.

Next, since $a \in \mbox{ inf } \{\frac{n\alpha +m\beta}{\alpha}:\frac{n\alpha +m\beta}{\alpha}>0; n,m\in \mathbb{Z}\} $ it follows
that
$$
\mathbb Z a \alpha \subseteq \{n\alpha +m\beta: n,m\in \mathbb{Z}\}  \,.
$$

Complete the contradiction by observing that the above inclusion must be equality, as otherwise you can create an element $d \in\mbox{ inf } \{\frac{n\alpha +m\beta}{\alpha}:\frac{n\alpha +m\beta}{\alpha}>0; n,m\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ with
$$
0 < d< a
$$
which is not possible.

You can now reach the contradiction:
$$
\mathbb Z a \alpha = \{n\alpha +m\beta: n,m\in \mathbb{Z}\}
$$
gives that
$$
\alpha =ka \alpha \\
\beta=la \alpha$$
The first relation gives $a \in \mathbb Q$, and then the second contradicts the linear independence over $\mathbb Q$.

---

Next, show that $\{n\alpha +m\beta: n,m\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ If $(e,f)$ is dense in the line $\mathbb R \alpha$ . Indeed, if $(e,f) \subseteq \mathbb R$ is any interval, by the above there exists some $m,n$

$$
0<\frac{n\alpha +m\beta}{\alpha}< f-e
$$
Pick the smallest $k \in \mathbb Z$ such that $k\frac{n\alpha +m\beta}{\alpha}>e$ and show that $k(n \alpha+m\beta) \in (e\alpha ,f \alpha)$.

---

FInally, since $f$ is constant on $\{ n\alpha +m\beta : m,n \in \mathbb Z\}$ and continuous, it is constant on its closure which is $\mathbb R \alpha$. The claim follows.

---

**Case 2**  $\alpha, \beta$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb R$.

In this case you can show that there exists some $R>0$ such that for each $z \in \mathbb C$ there exists $m,n \in \mathbb Z$ such that
$$
|z-m\alpha-n \beta| \leq R \,.
$$

Since $f$ is bounded on $\{ w : |w| \leq R \}$, the above implies that $f$ is bounded on $\mathbb C$.

Comment: I think something is still missing from the OP's problem setup.  Let $\alpha, \beta$ be purely imaginary but linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$, e.g. $\alpha = i, \beta = i\sqrt 2$.  Then the set $\{n\alpha + m\beta : n,m \in \mathbb Z\}$ is contained in the imaginary axis and the closure intersects the real axis only at the origin.  Of course the final conclusion follows because function $f$ now becomes constant on the imaginary axis rather than on the real axis, but something needs adjustment in the problem setup.

Comment: @hardmath I assumed that $\alpha,\beta$ are real, will fix it soon.